# cannot access to google account from my codeIgniter project

Tags: codeigniter, oauth-2.0, account

I'm trying to integrate google calendar in my codeIgniter application .There is a detail in the API that I didn't underderstand.
In order to authorize the application to access to the google account, OAuth2 is used. After setting the application's name, the client ID , ect, here is what should be done (according to the tuto) :

```
if ($this->input->get('code')) 
{
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
{ 
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) 
{ 
    $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public');
    print 'Your Activities: <pre>' . print_r($activities, true) . '</pre>';

    // We're not done yet. Remember to update the cached access token.
    // Remember to replace $_SESSION with a real database or memcached.
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} 
else 
{
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<a href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

I did this, but I am always redirected to the page "connect Me". I don't really understand what this com does mean :

```
// We're not done yet. Remember to update the cached access token.
// Remember to replace $_SESSION with a real database or memcached.
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you please make your code somewhat readable first. Thanks!

Comment: On which step of the [OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) exactly does this fail?

Comment: when I click on Connect Me and connect on my google account , it redirects me to the same page "Connect Me". $this->input->get('code')) , (isset($_SESSION['token'])) and $client->getAccessToken())  are always evaluated to false

Comment: What URL are you redirected to when redirected back from Google? (feel free to obfuscate any key)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson the same URL that I put in $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/*********/index.php/public/calendar') , it's the home of my website

Comment: Hi Can you please post complete controller code, so its easy to under how you load the google client classes.